# Make CSS Image a link

Tags: css, image, html, hyperlink

I'm just working on a site and I need an image in the top right corner that will link to another site when clicked. I created this in the CSS file:

```
div.image:before {
content:url(http://LinkToMyImage);
max-height: 169px;
max-width: 220px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
```

Then add this html:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

It appears exactly how I want it but it's obviously not a link, is there a way I can make this linkable? I have tried href to the div but that does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with an `<a>` tag?

Comment: It's impossible to make generated content linkable unless it's content within an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish the exact same thing by simply using an anchor tag. Also, there's no need to be so specific with your css by referencing the element your class applies to. That will take quite a bit longer to process than just using the class name.

If you need a higher level of specificity, target your element with another class name. Avoiding a specific element makes your code more flexible should the markup need to change in the future.

Change your html to:

```
<a class="image"></a>
```

and your css to:

```
.image:before {
    content:url('http://LinkToMyImage');
    // You should also be able to safely eliminate `display: block;`
    // when setting `position: absolute`, but included it just in case you
    // experienced problems setting width and height
    display: block;
    height: 169px;
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    // top 0 is usually inferred when setting position: absolute;
    // you should be able to remove this
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to change the HTML to `<a class="image"></a>`? Right now, it's exactly as it is in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon! I hate it when I get stuck on simple things like this... Literally spent 3 hours trying to figure this out before asking here and the fix of course took seconds. Thanks again!